# Symfony генерация Entity без префикса таблицы

Tags: symfony2, symfony, doctrine, entity, doctrine2

Вопрос по Symfony
Возможно ли сгенерировать Entity из уже готовых таблиц в базе БЕЗ префикса?
Просто при генерации создаются файлы с именем вида: E3rfBook
Где E3rf - и есть префикс в таблице :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартным генератором сущности это сделать невозможно.

Но всегда можно написать свою имплементацию стандартного генератора сущностей. А также сделать какой-нибудь listener, который будет подставлять префиксы. Но если это нужно только для одного проекта, то проще просто написать скрипт, который пробежит и поправит все имена файлов и соответствующие им имена классов. Думаю, что многие IDE способны справиться с этой задачей сами.